# Reusing Jasmine Spy with different andCallFake() method

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I am attempting to write some advanced tests in jasmine (version 1.3) where I am setting up a spy on the `$.getJSON()` method. This is being set up in the `beforeEach` block seen here:

```
describe 'the Controller', ->
    beforeEach ->
    Fixtures.createTestData()
    jqXHR = Fixtures.jqXHR
    section = new section({el:appDom})

    response = Fixtures.createSectionsSearchResponse()
    spyOn($, 'getJSON').andCallFake( ->
        jqXHR.resolve(response)
    )
```

I then go through the search query as usual (which works just fine).

In one of my later tests, I have a second API that is pinged. I would like to change the response that is being sent, but can't seem to get anything to work. [This Blog](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/blog/javascript-testing-with-jasminebdd.html) seems to imply that I could just reuse the spy with a different `andCallFake()`, but it does not seem to be working. I get the original response object rather than my overridden method

```
    $.getJSON.andCallFake( ->
        jqXHR.resolve({"count":4})
    )
```

Any thoughts on how I could reuse or destroy the original spy on method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the spy.

From [Jasmine guide](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-30):

```
it("can be reset", function() {
    foo.setBar(123);
    foo.setBar(456, "baz");

    expect(foo.setBar.calls.any()).toBe(true);

    foo.setBar.calls.reset();

    expect(foo.setBar.calls.any()).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: I should have said, I am using 1.3. We have not yet upgraded to 2.0. Sorry about that!

Comment: Resetting spies exists in Jasmine 1.3 too

Comment: The Jasmine 1.3 documentation makes no reference to resetting spies and your example does not seem to work.

Comment: You can find an example in Jasmine's Github, on the 1.3 branch - https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/1_3_x/spec/core/SpySpec.js#L183

Answer (score 2):

The [Jasmine 2.0 documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-31) describes the reset() method, but the [Jasmine 1.3 documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html) does not mention it.

For Jasmine 1.3, I believe what you're looking for is

```
foo.setBar.reset();
```

The equivalent portion of Jasmine's 2.0 documentation translated into 1.3 syntax would be as follows:

```
it("can be reset", function() {
  foo.setBar(123);
  foo.setBar(456, "baz");

  expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled();

  foo.setBar.reset();

  expect(foo.setBar).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

[Here's a fiddle as well.](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/xLfmktxq/)